# TestStack White performance slow and speed up

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, white-framework

I am using TestStack White to automate a test scenario in a Telerik Winforms application.

The application has plenty of elements and if I directly search for an element, the run would just stale and never end.

So I did the manual hierarchy search to dig into element levels to save the performance and make it work.

Then the code looks in a not neat way as I heavily use foreach to do the loop myself.

Is this the proper way to cope with the performance or we have better ways to 
have both neat code and good performance when using TestStack White?

Cheers:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.RawElementBasedSearch = true;
        CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.MaxElementSearchDepth = 2;
        var applicationDirectory = "D:\\Software\\ABC Handling System";
        var applicationPath = Path.Combine(applicationDirectory, "ABCClient.GUI.exe");
        Application application = Application.Launch(applicationPath);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Window window = application.GetWindow("[AB2] - ABC Handling System 2 - [Entity Search]", InitializeOption.NoCache);
        ListBox listbox = window.Get<ListBox>();
        ListItem dispatchButton = listbox.Items.Find(i=>i.Name.Equals("Display"));
        dispatchButton.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        SearchCriteria sc = SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Pane).AndIndex(3);
        UIItemContainer groupbox = (UIItemContainer)window.MdiChild(sc);

        UIItemContainer pane1 = null;
        foreach (IUIItem automationElement in groupbox.Items)
        {
            if (automationElement.Name == "radSplitContainer1")
            {
                pane1 = (UIItemContainer)automationElement;
                break;
            }
        }

        UIItemContainer pane2 = null;
        foreach (IUIItem automationElement in pane1.Items)
        {
            if (automationElement.Name == "splitPanel1")
            {
                pane2 = (UIItemContainer)automationElement;
                break;
            }
        }

        Table table = null;
        foreach (IUIItem automationElement in pane2.Items)
        {
            if (automationElement.Name == "Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView ; 247;14")
            {
                table = (Table)automationElement;
                break;
            }
        }

        TableRow row = table.Rows[9];
        string s = row.ToString();
    }
```

Update on 05/11/2019:

It turned out TestStack White is not the best solution for my multi-row grid app regarding its performance.

Actually we managed to have developed something from the grid side by developers, and we hook those functions up. So we were using AutoIt + Customized Application side hooks. Some really good controls there.

Yes, we succeeded in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah instead of doing the looping yourself you would just use the Get on each of the retrieved elements. Oddly when I dig down through the code it is using [AutomationElement.FindFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromPoint);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) which I am not sure how it traverses the tree to find it's elements. I would give the follow code a try and see if it is more or less performant in your application.

```
CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.RawElementBasedSearch = true;
CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.MaxElementSearchDepth = 2;
var applicationDirectory = "D:\\Software\\ABC Handling System";
var applicationPath = Path.Combine(applicationDirectory, "ABCClient.GUI.exe");
Application application = Application.Launch(applicationPath);
Thread.Sleep(5000);

Window window = application.GetWindow("[AB2] - ABC Handling System 2 - [Entity Search]", InitializeOption.NoCache);
ListBox listbox = window.Get<ListBox>();
ListItem dispatchButton = listbox.Get<ListItem>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Display"));
dispatchButton.Click();
Thread.Sleep(5000);

UIItemContainer groupbox = window.MdiChild(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Pane).AndIndex(3));
UIItemContainer pane1 = groupbox.Get<UIItemContainer>(SearchCriteria.ByText("radSplitContainer1"));
UIItemContainer pane2 = pane1.Get<UIItemContainer>(SearchCriteria.ByText("splitPanel1"));
Table table = pane2.Get<Table>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView ; 247;14")); ;
TableRow row = table.Rows[9];
string s = row.ToString();
```

I am getting everything from the previous element in an attempt to limit the portion of the tree it is scanning. From the looks of White's code this may have no affect other than reducing the amount of boiler plate on the front end depending on the performance of [AutomationElement.FindFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromPoint);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

Also the ByText search criteria maps to the name property on a AutomationElement by calling [CreateForName](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/Finders/SearchConditionFactory.cs#L46) which is why I replaced all the checks against name with ByText.